# Activate deactivate music in android by checkbox

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm basically new in Android programming so I've got some problems with code.
One of those issues came when I tried to do like a Main Menu with the option "SETTINGS" where
I'd like to start and pause the music that's playing in my whole app.
The thing is that I've already created the code of the music by MediaPlayer in my MainMenu, but I don't know how to take that value or that variable and manipulate it in the SETTINGS activity.
This is what I already have.

```
public class ActivityMenu extends Activity
{
    private TextView lbl1, lbl2;
    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        lbl1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl1);
        lbl1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        lbl2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl2);
        lbl2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.barrelvolcano);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(100,100);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

        public void settings(View view)
    {
        Intent s = new Intent(this, ActivitySettings.class);
        startActivity(s);
    }
}
```

////and this is my ActivitySettings where I'ld like to manipulate the mediaPlayer

```
public class ActivitySettings extends Activity
{
    private CheckBox chkb1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        chkb1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkb1);

        chkb1.setOnClickListener(new CheckBox.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(chkb1.isChecked())
                {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    //AudioManager volumeControl = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    //volumeControl.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    //AudioManager volumeControl = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    //volumeControl.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
                }
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

As you can see, I've already tried an option but, is not what I want, to Mute all the Multimedia volume.
So if you know how can I solve my problem, I'll apreciate it a lot! Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to assume that a non-root application cannot affect the volume settings for the entire device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `startActivityForResult()` and  have a callback method within your ActivityMenu called `onActivityResult()`.  You can then report back if they unchecked the box and turn off the music in the ActivityMenu activity.  [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Comment: Thanks ObieMD5. You were helpfull for my boudt! I've solved my problem!